# change MenuItem visibility when clicked

Tags: android, case, visibility, menuitem

I'm trying to hide one `MenuItem` and make another visible when the first is selected.

The ID's for each are:

```
pencil: R.id.button_routines_edit
check mark: R.id.button_routines_edit_done
```

Here the relevant code:

```
  private boolean isEditing = false;

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
      // Handle item selection
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.button_routines_edit:
            // hide pencil icon, show checkmark
            isEditing = true;
        return true;
      case R.id.button_routines_edit_done:
            // show pencil icon, done editing
            isEditing = false;
        return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
      // hide pencil when editing and show check mark
      menu.findItem(R.id.button_routines_edit).setVisible(!isEditing);
      menu.findItem(R.id.button_routines_edit_done).setVisible(isEditing);
      return true;
  }
```

My problem is:
The Options Menu doesn't redraw the items when they're selected. In other words, the first isn't hidden and the second isn't shown.

Comment: you will need to use `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` or `setVisibility(View.GONE);` to make an View inviable

Comment: its not a view, its a menuitem, therefore that method does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

[invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) is only available in API 11+, unless you're using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

You're having this problem  because your `MenuItems` are show in the `ActionBar`, basically. If you place them in the overflow menu, you won't need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. this worked perfectly. i also read that you have to use this function because the action bar is always present, and using this function forces onPrepareOptionsMenu to be executed.

Comment: In case of ActionBarSherlock, `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` can be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, It must hide the Menu Item

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

          menu.getItem(R.id.button_routines_edit).setVisible(!isEditing);
          menu.getItem(R.id.button_routines_edit_done).setVisible(isEditing);
          return true;
      }
```