# Android: onOptionItemSelected set items Visible.GONE

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I have a search item, with 2 other items on the toolbar.

On clicking on the search item, I wish for the other 2 items to disappear and reappear when the search bar is closed.

Here is what i have tried thus far:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions_one_fragment, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    this.menu = menu;
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_item_one).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_item_two).setVisible(false);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This doesn't do anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018224/change-menuitem-visibility-when-clicked

Answer (score 0):

You should hide/remove menu item like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            menu.removeItem(R.id.action_item_one);
            menu.removeItem(R.id.action_item_two);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: You don't want to remove it if it should be visible/enabled later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes to a Menu and its items before it's show, Android says you should use the [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) callback.  This is called by Android just before the menu is shown, so you can make changes to it (and its items) there that will immediately take effect.

In your sample, you are only setting the menu option to be invisible in the case where the search option is selected.  That's probably not sufficient to do what you're asking.